# How to handle an old, abandoned Litecoin withdrawal from btc-e.com

Tags: litecoin, btce

In 2013 I bought some litecoins on btc-e.com.
I noticed this website is down by now.

I found a e-mail from 11/2013:
"Dear (my login name),

We received a request to withdraw 25.87814001 LTC on purse Lh2x1hcGiRnWJRwGdfJP26sB4zw8j54e6m

To confirm the transaction, go to:
(Removed link)

To cancel a transaction, go to:
(Removed link)

IP: (my ip address)
Login: (my login)

Regards,
Administration of BTC-E.COM"

On https://live.blockcypher.com/ltc/address/Lh2x1hcGiRnWJRwGdfJP26sB4zw8j54e6m/
I found this exact same transaction. Does this mean it still is in the wallet of btc-e? Or is this my external wallet it is transfered to?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had the exact same issue, even tracked it down by finding the withrdawal email from a withdrawal that I guess didn't go through.  My account is https://live.blockcypher.com/ltc/address/LcSLWWRpDtjpuiDXQnJPXwVvVtZGqeJNNa/.

Unfortunately I got the exact same email reply as you as well.  Maybe, there would be some legal action options, but that seems like a long shot.

Comment: Hello Ryan, thanks for your reply. You say you 'had' the exact issue. Is it fixed yet? What did you try so far?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't gotten the litecoins back, I've mostly given up hope.  Contacting wex.nz was the main thing I attempted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't believe we are the only two people with this problem

Answer (score 1):

I sent a message to the support centre of the new exchange (WEX.nz).
I got this automated reply:
"Hello! 
We informed in the news that we don't possess historical data on transaction and orders of the old platform, that's why we cannot approve or deny your words about funds deposit. The funds were credited to the new platform WEX.nz in the amount shown in your profile. During the period after BTCE closing and before WEX opening, all transactions were fulfilled out of control of the old platform as well out of control of the new one."

In my profile I got 0.00005462 Bitcoin and 0.00005462 Bitcoin Cash. Thats all.. It's worth about 1 USD.

How can I get those litecoins that still are on my address?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your litecoins are in that address (Lh2x1hcGiRnWJRwGdfJP26sB4zw8j54e6m), and have been untouched.

To claim it, you must find the exchange this address is linked too and see if the exchange has your correct litecoin balance.

To answer your question, this means that it is no longer in the wallet of btc-e as that address has the correct amount of funds in it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is this address the btc-e address or is it my address on another wallet? How do I find the exchange where this address is linked to?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The provided evidence suggests, that the withdrawal never took place as the funds are still at the mentioned address.

Hopefully either

- you have a backup of the private key of that address
- you are able to (still somehow) contact btc-e.com and get these keys

With that you can load them into another litecoin client.

Comment: So this address is a address in the btc-e wallet? Unfortunately I don't have the private keys. If you or someone else could help me with this, I would give you a nice reward if I'm able to succesfully recover the litecoins.